# Ignore text and extract number betwen 8 and 12 digits long

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to extract only a number if it's between 8 and 12 digits long, otherwise I wish it to be a blank.  However in the column of data there can be text which I want as a blank.

Have tried may alterations of the code below with different brackets, though I get an error

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
    isnumeric(dbo.worksheet_pvt.MPRNExpected) = 0 THEN '' ELSE(
        CASE WHEN(
            len(dbo.worksheet_pvt.MPRNExpected) >= 8
            AND len(dbo.worksheet_pvt.MPRNExpected) < 13
        ) THEN dbo.worksheet_pvt.MPRNExpected ELSE ''
    END
) AS [ MPRN Expected ]
```

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL, but your code is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, I would suggest:

```
select (case when p.MPRNExpected not like '%[^0-9]%' and
                  len(p.MPRNExpected) between 8 and 12
             then p.MPRNExpected
        end) as MPRN_Expected
       . . .
from dbo.worksheet_pvt p
```

Presumably, you don't want `isnumeric()`, because it allows characters such as `'.'`, `'-'`, and `'e'` in the "number".

The problem with your code is that you have two `case` expressions and they are not terminated correctly.

As a note, in MySQL, you would use regular expressions:

```
select (case when p.MPRNExpected regexp '^[0-9]{8-12}$'
             then p.MPRNExpected
        end) as MPRN_Expected
       . . .
from dbo.worksheet_pvt p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(COLUMN_NAME)=0 THEN '' ELSE 
CASE WHEN (LEN(COLUMN_NAME)>=8 AND LEN(COLUMN_NAME)<13) 
THEN COLUMN_NAME ELSE ''END END AS data FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Thanks.